# Object stops tracking mouse position when hovering over other objects C#

Tags: c#, button, mouseevent

I have a program which uses the mouse's .X position (relative to the form boundaries) to change the .Left value of a button Object.

The problem is that I have this button over the top of other objects like Picture Boxes, Buttons, TrackBar's etc. and when I hove over these other elements, the button stops tracking the mouse's .X position.

How can I make the button track the mouse movement regardless of the mouse doing other stuff on the form too? (I also need to interact with the other elements at the same time too).

## My Code:

```
/* i create the mousemove tracking event */    
this.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(btnBat1_MouseMove);

/* and use it by making a new method */
public void btnBat1_MouseMove(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  // I use the variable mouseXCo to change the button1.Left value.
  mouseXCo = e.X;
}
```

Thanks in advance guys :-)

Comment: It works for me. Try using MousePosition.X. Does it behave the same?

Comment: No, it is worse... and that still doesn't work for when hovering over other buttons!??

Comment: Might be worth noting that the buttons are in a panel (but the Picturebox isn't)

Comment: You'd have to wire up **all** the MouseMove() events for every control on your Form to the same routine for it to work the way you've envisioned.  When other controls (besides the Form) fire the event, the X and Y values will be relative to that control.  You could ignore those values and simply convert the current cursor position to Form coords using the Form's PointToClient() function.  If this is WinForms, then an alternate approach would be to implement IMessageFilter and track mouse movement that way.  This would give you a global hook (just for your application) for mouse movement.